# How to update a field's value by an incremental value without using loop in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `#temp` in SQL Server 2008 like this:

```
Id p_id h_no f_id
------------------
1  100  A01  null
2  200  A02  null
3  300  A02  null
4  400  null null
5  500  null null
6  600  A03  null
7  700  A01  null
8  400  null null
```

So basically, every record has a `p_id`, but may or may not have `h_no`.

What I want is to replace `f_id` values with a dummy incremental number based on:

- if `h_no` value of a record matches another(s), this (those) ones will have same `f_id`  (check ids:1 & 7 or ids:2 & 3 in the example)
- if `h_no` is null but `p_id` values are equal for some cases, they will have same `f_id` (check ids: 4 & 8 in the example)

For example, the sample table above should be:

```
Id p_id h_no f_id
-----------------
1  100  A01  1
2  200  A02  2
3  300  A02  2
4  400  null 3
5  500  null 4
6  600  A03  5
7  700  A01  1
8  400  null 3
```

I do not want to use a loop for this process. I am trying to find a more optimal solution for this. I need a query something like below, could not find the correct syntax.

```
declare @tempFID int = 1;

update t
set t.f_id = @tempFID++ --syntax error
from #temp t
inner join #temp t2 on t.Id = t2.Id
where (t.h_no is not null and t.h_no = t2.h_no) 
   or (t.h_no is null and t.p_id = t2.p_id)
```

I also tried but had syntax error:

```
update t
set t.f_id = (set @tempFID = @tempFID + 1) --syntax error
...
```

Any help would be so appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
       ,CASE WHEN h_no IS NULL THEN p_id ELSE MIN(p_id) OVER (PARTITION BY h_no) END as PIdGroup
    FROM
       @Table
)

, cteFIdValue AS (
    SELECT
       Id
       ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PIdGroup) as f_id
    FROM
       cte
)

UPDATE t
    SET f_id = u.f_id
FROM
    Table t
    INNER JOIN cteFIdValue u
    ON t.ID = u.ID
```

- Find the minimum p_id for each h_no and just leave it as the assigned p_id if h_no is null
- Then create a dense rank on the PidGroup
- Update the Table

so you have problems besides a syntax error in your code above.  First your join will only get the exact same record, you would have to change to `t.ID <> t2.ID` as left join and still need some sort of ranking.  honestly I am not positive what you are attempting there.

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm my friend. Thanks a lot for it and your explanations. I also appreciate if you briefly explain what DENSE_RANK() is doing, I never seen it before.

Answer (score -1):

This approach might be simpler:

```
update #temp
set f_id = isnull(f_id, 0) + 
case when condition1 is met then value 1
etc
when final condition is met then 0
else null
end
```

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, but I'm curious about the reason.

Comment: Because your answer, is incomplete with the (etc). f_id would be null if the ELSE condition of your Case expression is evaluated, it doesn't show how to determine when to use the p_id of its own record or another record when the h_no is shared, and it doesn't create a dense ranking to create the new psuedo f_id